# Why does .remove() not work in my setup?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently doing my first steps in jQuery and have a problem with [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). There are already a lot of questions from people with similar problems but they don't help me.

In a HTML file, I have a form and the following `div` that serves as an alert box and displays whether the form validated correctly or not. In its original state, the `div` contains a single button for closing it.

```
<div id="my-form-alert-box">
    <button id="my-form-alert-button" type="button" class="close">x</button>
</div>
```

When the HTML page loads for the first time, the alert box should not be displayed. That's why I add the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #my-form-alert-box {display: none;}
</style>
```

When the form gets submitted and validated, I append `<p>some text</p>` to this `div` and then the alert box is displayed. When I close the alert box using the button, it disappears but the `<p>some text</p>` is not removed. Why is this the case?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $myFormAlertBox = $('#my-form-alert-box');
    var $myFormAlertBoxParagraph = $('#my-form-alert-box p');

    $('#my-form-alert-button').on('click', function(event) {

        $myFormAlertBoxParagraph.remove();
        $myFormAlertBox.hide();

    });

    $('#my-form').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            // ...
            success: function(data) {

                // The content of the alert box should be removed
                // and the alert box itself should be hidden also when
                // the form gets submitted again and not only when the
                // button is clicked
                $myFormAlertBoxParagraph.remove();
                $myFormAlertBox.hide();

                // data contains <p>some text</p>
                $myFormAlertBox.append(data).show(); 
            }

        });

        event.preventDefault();

    });        

});
```

Appending the data works fine, but removing it does not. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show the complete content that you get in `data` from the ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial assignment of $myFormAlertBoxParagraph will fail as there isn't a paragraph in your markup when it is called.  Adding a 'placeholder' paragraph into your markup should fix it.  This explains why the .remove() will fail.

For your ajax, try something like this to keep the variables assigned with their new values:

```
//...
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
        // Remove the existing paragraph.
        $myFormAlertBoxParagraph.remove();

        // This updates the paragraph object with the new one.
        $myFormAlertBoxParagraph = $(data);

        // Add the new paragraph and ensure the alert box is visible.
        $myFormAlertBox.append($myFormAlertBoxParagraph).show();
    }
});
//...
```

This will remove the paragraph tag from the alert box, and add the new one.  There's no need to .hide() it and then immediately .show() it afterwards.  However, adding the .show() after the .append() will cover you if it has been hidden by your click event.

Comment: I don't want to use `.empty()` on the entire `div` because then the button will be removed as well. But I want to keep the button and only remove the paragraph.

Comment: My mistake.  I didn't read the markup closely enough.  I have updated my answer which should work for you now.

Comment: Your code works, thank you. As already stated in the comment of one of the other answers, my problem was mainly related to using only one selector and assigning it to a variable. Your code partly solves that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think your selector is running before you update the content. The selector can only see what's in there when it initially runs.

Comment: You are right. My problem disappears when I don't assign the selectors to variables as seen above but just use the selectors directly each time. But I've read somewhere that assigning selectors to variables is more efficient than always calling a new selector. Is that true?

Comment: It's true - but that freezes the value in time. It's more efficient to use a variable if the value isn't changing, as opposed to using the selector which must execute every time you use it. You need to get a fresh value after the content changes.

Comment: This is only valid if you don't change the DOM part that is reflected in the jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects are not live. You create the $myFormAlertBoxParagraph object before you even append the `<p>`. So this object is empty and will be empty "forever" because you never reassign it.

Comment: You are right. It was wrong to assign the selector to a variable.